# How to connect an abstract signal to a slot within the interface's constructor?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, signals-slots

I have an abstract class that contains the pure virtual signal and a class derived from `QObject`. I want to connect that signal to derived class's slot.

```
class MSys : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MSys(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
    virtual ~MSys() {}

public slots:
    void onRequset();
};

class AbsView
{
protected:
    AbsView() : m_sys(new MSys)
    {
    // QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(request()), m_sys, SLOT(onRequset()));
    /* What can I do here !? */
    }

public:
    virtual ~AbsView() {}

signals:
    virtual void request() = 0;

private:
    MSys *m_sys;
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(AbsView, "AbsView")
```

This isn't a problem once the constructor is finished: then the `dynamic_cast<QObject*>(this)` will work within any of interface's methods. But within the constructor, it seems impossible.

Is there some way of doing it?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @MatthewRead  Thanks for asking. `this` in `QObject::connect` is not a QObject.

Comment: Oh, well `AbsView` would need to extend `QObject`.

Comment: Alright, is the down vote logical ??!!
In this answer I just given abstract class as example. What if it was an interface ??

Comment: @MatthewRead I'm using it for multiple-inheritance. Inheriting QObject twice is not allowed. So that is not an option. Again thank you sir.

Comment: @KubaOber Thank you. Didn't my question say from the `constructor`.

Comment: Ah, knowing that you want to multiply-inherit is important.  I agree with Kuba that the constructor is not special in this regard.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, interfaces should be abstract classes, and their constructors shouldn't be doing anything at all. So this is bad design.

If you insist on doing things such way, the semantics of C++ prevents us from doing it exactly as you state. When you multiply-inherit, a `dynamic_cast` to `C` will fail until the constructor of `C` is entered:

```
struct Interface {
  Interface() { assert(dynamic_cast<QObject*>(this) == 0); }
};

struct C : public QObject, public Interface {
  C() { assert(dynamic_cast<QObject*>(this)); }
};
```

So, we need some way of delaying the connection until the full object has been constructed, or at least until the `QObject` part of it is available.

A simple way would be for the interface to explicitly require the base to be constructed:

```
struct Interface {
  Interface(QObject * base) {
    connect(base, ...);
  }
};

struct C : public QObject, public Interface {
  C() : Interface(this) {}
};
```

The constructor signature nicely expresses the intent: `Interface` is meant to be used on classes deriving from `QObject`. It will not work on those that don't.

Another way is to delay the connection until the event loop has had a chance to run. This is acceptable if the connection isn't needed sooner than that. This doesn't require the `Interface` constructor to be passed an explicit pointer to the base class.

The timer is owned by the event dispatcher for the current thread, that way it won't leak even if the event loop isn't ever started.

```
class Interface {
public:
  virtual void request() = 0; // entirely optional
  Interface() {
    auto timer = new QTimer(QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance());
    timer.start(0);
    QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this, timer]{
      timer.deleteLater();
      connect(dynamic_cast<QObject*>(this), SIGNAL(request()), ...);
    });    
  }
};
```

Please note that in all cases it's entirely superfluous to have the signal declared virtual in the interface. The `Interface`'s constructor can check if the signal is present, and assert it, or even always `abort()`.

Merely by declaring a virtual signal doesn't guarantee that the signal is actually a signal. The following will not work, even though the compiler provides no diagnostics to the contrary:

```
struct Interface {
  signals:
    virtual void aSignal() = 0;
};

struct Implementation : public QObject, public Interface {
  void aSignal() {} // not really a signal!
};
```

This will detect the missing signal at runtime:

```
struct Interface {
  // No need for virtual signal!
  Interface(QObject * base) {
    Q_ASSERT(base->metaObject()->indexOfSignal("request()") != -1);
  }
};

struct Implementation : public QObject, public Interface {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_SIGNAL void reuest(); // a typo
  Implementation() : Interface(this) {} // will assert!
};
```

The best way to ensure that the virtual signal is followed could be to do both, and to declare the signal implementation as an override:

```
struct Interface {
  virtual void aSignal() = 0;
  Interface(QObject * base) {
    Q_ASSERT(base->metaObject()->indexOfSignal("request()") != -1);
  }
};

struct Implementation : public QObject, public Interface {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_SIGNAL void request() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
  Implementation() : Interface(this) {}
};
```

The compiler will catch typos *even if* you never instantiate the `Implementation`, and the interface will check at runtime that the implementation's signal is actually a signal, and not some other method.

It must also be noted that the `signals:` section of the `Interface` is bogus.

1. `signals` is a preprocessor macro with empty expansion: to the compiler, it does nothing.
2. `Interface` is not a `QObject`, and is thus ignored by the moc.
3. `signals:` is only meaningful to moc iff it is in a class that **both**:

   - derives from `QObject`, and
   - contains the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Generally speaking, virtual signals make little sense. They are all "virtual" in the sense that you can connect things without giving the compiler a virtual method.

Finally, they don't work with the Qt 5 compile-time-verified syntax either, since `Interface` is not a concrete `QObject`-deriving class with a proper signal

Comment: Actually the part "delaying the connection" was already in my mind. Your first solution is what I did but was thinking of a better way. That is why I asked the question here. Any way, as the answer is alternatively correct I'm marking it as correct answer. 
+1 for detailed writeup. Thank you very much..